# Globbing accented files in Bash

Tags: bash, macos, glob

I'm trying to verify a file exists in `Bash`. I know the file name (in a variable) but not the extension (can be `.pmdl` or `.umdl`).

on OSX, this works:

```
$> ls
ecole.pmdl
$> filename="ecole"
$> ls "$filename."[pu]mdl
ecole.pmdl
```

But it doesn't when the file name contains an accent:

```
$> ls
école.pmdl
$> filename="école"
$> ls "$filename."[pu]mdl
ls: école.[pu]mdl: No such file or directory
```

However it works if I don't use globbing:

```
$> ls "$filename."pmdl
école.pmdl
```

I'm looking for a simple solution that works in both Linux & OSX. [This is the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764864/does-utf-8-encoding-messes-file-globbing-and-greping) I found on that topic.

Edit:

```
$> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**Edit 2:**

Short version to prove that the scenario fails (systematically) with same `é` char on OSX Bash v3.2.57. The same scenario on Linux Bash 4.3.30 works systematically (found).

```
$> touch é.txt
$> ls é*
ls: é*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why does it say `école.?mdl: No such file or directory`? Where did it get the question mark from?

Comment: It works here. What version of bash are you using? Do: `bash --version`.

Comment: @sorontar question updated

Comment: @thatotherguy sorry typo, question updated (and re-tested to make sure)

Comment: @Alexylem [Please read this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10484).

Comment: Have you tested `echo e*` (no accent), with the file école created?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Either: Use one of the following **workarounds**:

  - `ls "$(iconv -t UTF-8-MAC <<<'école')."[pu]mdl` - most generic, but cumbersome.
  - `ls $'e\x{cc}\x{81}cole'.[pu]mdl` - hard to remember, and specific to the diacritic at hand (acute accent, `´`).
  - `ls e?cole.[pu]mdl` - simple to type and remember, but limited to 1 combining diacritic and can yield false positives.
- Or: **install Bash 4.3.30 or higher** via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and use it instead of the Bash 3.x that macOS still comes with: `brew install bash`.

Gory details below.

---

With respect to **non-ASCII characters**,

- the **macOS filesystem**, **[HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)**, speaks *only* **NFD** (***decomposed*** Unicode normalization form), where **accented letters** are represented by ***2 or more* Unicode codepoints**: the *base letter*, followed by the *combining diacritic(s)* (accent mark(s)):

  - In the case of `é`:

    - The ASCII *base letter* - `e` (`U+0065`, UTF-8 encoding `0x65`)
    - *followed by* the *combining* acute accent (the `´` above the preceding base letter, `U+0301`, UTF-8 encoding `0xcc 0x81`).
  - Some accented characters decompose to a base letter followed by *multiple* combining diacritics, such as in the case of `Ṹ`.
  - Note that the filesystem accepts NFC strings (see next point) when *creating* files and matching filenames *literally*, and automatically translates them to their NFD equivalent (decomposes them).
  - As an aside: a notable critic of HFS+ in general and its use of NFD in particular is Linus Torvalds, as expressed in [this article](http://www.cio.com/article/2868393/linus-torvalds-apples-hfs-is-probably-the-worst-file-system-ever.html).
- **Typically**, however - such as when you type characters in a terminal or in most editors - **NFC**  (***composed*** Unicode normalization form) is used, where (customary) **accented letters** are represented by ***1* Unicode codepoint**:

  - In the case of `é`: *single* Unicode character `U+00E9`, UTF-8 encoding `0xc3 0xa9`.
  - **NFD and NFC *should* be treated as *equivalent***, but as of **Bash 3.x - as found on macOS - aren't**: **NFC (and also NFD) input is taken *as-is* when *globbing*** (either as typed in the terminal or as saved by most editors in UTF-8-encoded scripts) and matches it *codepoint by codepoint* against the filesystem's NFD representation, without recognizing equivalent NFC and NFD representations.
    In effect, that means that **accented NFC characters typed in the terminal or as produced by most editors do NOT match their NFD equivalents in the HFS+ filesystem**.
  - By contrast, specifying *literal* filenames - *without globbing* - is not affected: `ls école`, expressed as NFC, does find the file named `école`, which is stored in NFD - presumably, because Bash just passes the NFC representation to a *system* function that does recognize the equivalence.

Read about these **Unicode normal (normalization) forms** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms).

In short: **Bash *should* recognize NFD and NFC representations as equivalent, but doesn't, as of the obsolete version that macOS 10.12.1 comes with - Bash 3.2.57.**

While the problem has been fixed as of at least Bash 4.3.30 *when run on macOS*, **Apple isn't updating to Bash 4.x** versions for *licensing* reasons (see below for a solution).

See the bottom of this post for a look at the *Linux* world.

---

There are **workarounds** for globbing filenames with accented characters on macOS:

- [*if feasible*] Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), **install the latest 4.x Bash version** and use it instead of the one that comes with macOS: `brew install bash`.

  - Note that if you use such a Bash version (>= 4.3.30), not only are the other workarounds described below no longer *necessary*, they actually *stop working*, because Bash then only supports *NFC* input as part of globbing patterns (but maps it correctly onto NFD equivalents in the filesystem).
- [*robust, but more elaborate*] **Use `iconv -t UTF-8-MAC`** to convert your Bash string literal from NFC to NFD so that it matches the filesystem representation:
  `ls "$(iconv -t UTF-8-MAC <<<'école')."[pu]mdl`

  - Alternatively, it is possible, but obscure and cumbersome, to use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to represent the exact NFD UTF-8 byte sequence:
    `ls $'e\x{cc}\x{81}cole'.[pu]mdl`
- [*simpler, but suboptimal*] Represent each accented character as `<base-char>?`, because, from Bash's perspective, the accented character, as reported by the filesystem, amounts to the base character `e` followed by *another* character (the combining diacritic; adjust accordingly for *multiple* combining diacritics).
  (This approach is obviously suboptimal, because it won't match *just* `é`, but *any* two-character sequence starting with `e`):
  `ls e?cole.[pu]mdl`

---

The **[ext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_system) filesystem** used by many **Linux** distros **stores filenames *exactly as specified***:

In other words: a file created with an NFC name is stored as such, as is a file with an NFD name.

Therefore, `ext` considers NFC and NFD distinct forms, because their byte-level representations differ, so it even allows files of the (conceptually) same name that differ only in Unicode normal form - for instance, files named `$'e\xcc\x81cole'` and `$'\xc3\xa9cole'` are indistinguishable when printed by `ls` (`école`), but are distinct files(!).

Consequently - and appropriately - Bash versions on *Linux* do *not* recognize NFC / NFD equivalence, even in versions >= 4.3.30 (unlike on macOS).

*Caveat*: `dash`, which acts as `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu, for instance, as of Ubuntu 16.04 is not locale-aware (multi-byte character-encoding aware), at least when *globbing*: globbing symbol `?` matches a single *byte* rather than a single *character* (as defined by the active locale's character encoding, as reflected in locale category `LC_CTYPE`, which is typically UTF-8). Thus, in order to match a single non-ASCII character, you need to know how many bytes the UTF-8 encoding of that character is composed of, and use a `?` for each byte; for instance, NFC `é` (2 bytes) would have to be matched with `??`.<sup>[1]</sup>

This may matter when you use globbing inside scripts whose shebang line is `#!/bin/sh`.

In practice, NFD strings are rarely encountered, so with NFC strings used both to create files and match them later by globs, the problem with differing Unicode normal forms that macOS experiences rarely surfaces on Linux.

---

<sup>[1] `dash` aims to be a fast, POSIX-compliant shell implementation (that is largely *confined* to POSIX features), but in this case it appears to fall short: the [part of the POSIX spec. describing the pattern-matching notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) clearly talks about *characters*, not *bytes*: `A <question-mark> is a pattern that shall match any character.`

Support for multi-byte character encodings is described in the section on [Character Sets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html).</sup>

Comment: The "state of mind" about characters in POSIX is the old idea of only ASCII. Look at the [character list in this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html), and to [the first line here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_02): "The POSIX locale shall contain 256 **single-byte characters**". Similar to the concept of a `char` in c language.

Comment: @sorontar: I appreciate your continued, tireless efforts to make my answer better, but you may notice that it says in my answer (emphasis added) "reflected in locale category `LC_CTYPE`, which is _typically UTF-8_". Real-world locales on modern Unix systems are UTF-8 based. E.g., on my US English Ubuntu 16.04 systems, `locale` outputs `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. What you're referring to is the locale _literally named_ `POSIX` (its alias is `C`), and the single-byte logic applies only when _that specific locale_ is in effect. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html

Comment: Well, I found a way to give you some credits for all your effort ;-). Keep going!

Comment: Are you saying that a `?` in a pattern in dash will match more than a byte in some locales? Do you have an example of such event ?.

Comment: @sorontar: No, what I'm saying is that it _should_ do that, and the fact that it _doesn't_ do that is a notable limitation that, as far as I can tell, is a deviation from the POSIX spec. On a Linux system with `LC_CTYPE` set to `*.UTF-8`, try `touch é` in `bash`, and you'll see that `ls ?` matches that file. Its name is composed of _two bytes_ that make up the _single_ accented _character_, and Bash correctly recognizes the 2-byte sequence as a single character. By contrast, `dash` only matches it as `ls ??`, with a `?` for each _byte_.

Comment: Exactly: ```dash only matches it as `ls ??` with a ? for each byte```. Why?. ... ... Isn't BSD ash one of the best examples of the old Bourne shell ?

Comment: That you'll have to ask the maintainers of `dash`. The Bourne shell precedes the POSIX shell specification. I have no idea when locales and support for multi-byte-on-demand encodings such as UTF-8 was introduced, but it's been part of POSIX for quite a while.

Comment: I am having trouble getting your first solution to work on macOS with bash 5.0.3. I have a file that starts with "Abé". when I run `ls "$(iconv -t UTF-8-MAC <<<'Abé')"*` it says `gls: cannot access 'Abé*': No such file or directory` . (I have alias that substitutes for ls for gls.)

Comment: @mklement0 OK, I've done it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642012/globbing-and-renaming-accented-files-in-bash-continued My problem has a slightly different form, but I think the root is the same. If you have any advice, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 2):

It is a requirement of HFS+[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1173/_index.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Design) (Apple filesystem) to store Unicode strings in decomposed form (as opposed to a [pre-composed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character)).

It is then that a character like `é` of Unicode code position U+0E9 is decomposed into the **two** characters `e` and `´` of Unicode code positions U+065 and U+0301 respectively.

You can see this difference by creating a clean empty directory and doing:

```
$ a='é'
$ echo "$a" >.text
$ touch "$a"
$ ls > .list
```

And then comparing the output of this two commands:

```
$ od -vAn -tx1c .text
  c3  a9  0a
 303 251  \n

$ od -vAn -tx1c .list
  65  cc  81  0a
   e 314 201  \n
```

Which are not equal.

You may try using this pattern in your system:

```
ls "e$(echo -e '\xcc\x81')cole".[pu]mdl
```

Which is simply the expression that the `é` is represented by two characters in the filesystem.

Understand that this problem has been resolved in newer bash versions.

Reference:

[How to enter special characters so that bash terminal understands them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them)

Answer (score 1):

## **é != é**

```
$ echo "école." | xxd 
00000000: c3a9 636f 6c65 0a                        ..cole.

$ echo "école." | xxd
00000000: 65cc 8163 6f6c 650a                      e..cole.
```

So by this we can see they are different characters:

```
$ echo -e "\x65\xCC\x81"
é
$ echo -e "\xC3\xA9"
é
```

> *You are not using the same character in your filename as set in your
>   variable.*

```
for i in {1..3}; do f="école"; ls "$f."[pu]mdl; echo "$i: $f."[pu]mdl; done
for i in {1..3}; do f="école"; ls "$f."[pu]mdl; echo "$i: $f."[pu]mdl; done
ls: école.[pu]mdl: No such file or directory
1: école.[pu]mdl
ls: école.[pu]mdl: No such file or directory
2: école.[pu]mdl
ls: école.[pu]mdl: No such file or directory
3: école.[pu]mdl
école.pmdl
1: école.[pu]mdl
école.pmdl
2: école.[pu]mdl
école.pmdl
3: école.[pu]mdl
```

This error can be difficult to reproduce simply because copying and pasting the character from one place to another can get translated by the editor, shell, etc. completely changing it. It may look like the same character, but it's genuinely different by seemingly indistinguishable details.

Comment: I'm shocked. I verified and technically the `é` from the file actually comes from that variable. But that explains why I also have simple equality check failure where the two strings print out exactly the same...

Comment: `touch "é.txt"; ls é*` => `ls: é*: No such file or directory`. However `ls é.txt` works. No copy paste...

Comment: While I was testing this it seemed to act as an escape character at one point, so I would be careful on how you use this character as it might introduce unintended behavior...

Comment: How about equivalence classes, `[=e=]`? Depending on the locale, they might match all the different `é`.

Comment: @sorontar this is why I haven't accepted this answer. On OSX: `touch école.pmdl ecole.pmdl; ls ecole.[pu]mdl #OK; ls école.[pu]mdl #KO`