# Globbing and renaming accented files in Bash (continued)

Tags: bash, macos, character-encoding, glob

This is a continuation of the following question:

[Globbing accented files in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062427/globbing-accented-files-in-bash/)

I asked it there, but was encouraged to ask a new question.

I have about 20,000 thousand files, many of which need to be renamed. If they have the same prefix, they are numbered sequentially regardless of extension. This isn't my problem, it just explains the options I'm using with the `rename` command below.

**Problem:** Several filenames contain accented characters, which seem to prevent globs from being expanded. The `rename` command thus doesn't rename the appropriate files.

I am on macOS 10.14.4, running Bash 5.0.3.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/bash

filenamestem="Vvért, Cdeós"

rename -n -X -N 001 -e '$_ = "'"${filenamestem}"'_$N"' "${filenamestem}"*
```

Here is the output when `set -x` is added:

```
+ filenamestem='Vvért, Cdeós'
+ rename -n -X -N 001 -e '$_ = "Vvért, Cdeós_$N"' 'Vvért, Cdeós*'
'Vvért, Cdeós*' would be renamed to 'Vvért, Cdeós_001'
```

Here are some of the files in the directory:

```
'Vvért, Cdeós copy.doc'
'Vvért, Cdeós copy.pdf'
'Vvért, Cdeós-2 copy.docx'
'Vvért, Cdeós-2.docx'
'Vvért, Cdeós.doc'
'Vvért, Cdeós.pdf'
```

When the filenames lack accents or other diacritics, the command works wonderfully.

I have tried

```
rename -n -X -N 001 -e '$_ = "'"${filenamestem}"'_$N"' "$(iconv -t UTF-8-MAC <<< "${filenamestem}")"*
```

according to the solution to the question mentioned above, but receive the same output:

```
+ filenamestem='Vvért, Cdeós'
++ iconv -t UTF-8-MAC
+ rename -n -X -N 001 -e '$_ = "Vvért, Cdeós_$N"' 'Vvért, Cdeós*'
'Vvért, Cdeós*' would be renamed to 'Vvért, Cdeós_001'
```

Finally, the files I've been testing on reside on a local disk, which is using APFS. The files I'd ultimately like to rename are on a server, whose file system with which I'm not familiar, in case this is important. In any case, I have the same problem when running these commands on both sets of files.

Would anyone know how to have this work on filenames with diacritics?

Comment: Just to gather additional information: Why aren't you using the Bash version that comes with macOS 10.14 (v3.2.57)? `rename` isn't a stock command on macOS: where does yours come from, and what's its specific version?

Comment: Another package from Homebrew needed the upgraded Bash. I just changed the path after the shebang to /bin/sh and /bin/bash to see if it did anything, but the result is the same. I installed rename also from Homebrew. Rename's version is 1.600.

Comment: Wait, I changed the paths in the wrong script. It works!

Comment: Changing /usr/local/bin/bash to /bin/bash seems to have fixed it. It now seems even to work when I remove the iconv statement! I'm a little stunned and will come back if I have further troubles. Thanks!

Comment: why were you using `rename` and not `mv`?

Comment: @cdarke I guess I could have used `mv`, but the `rename` man page gave me an idea for how to renumber the files, and so I thought I would use it. Would it have been easier with `mv`?

Comment: Since I don't know `rename` (it is non-standard) then I can't say.

Comment: @cdarke No problem. Thanks!